# IOS/Objective-C: Testing date for null very slow

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I have some code that is running very slow. I narrowed down the issue to the following lines.  If commented out, the code runs rapidly.  If present, this process can take 30 seconds or more although no error is reported by the compiler or at runtime.

I have a date in a temporary object as follows:

```
 NSDate *lastedited = importObject.lastedited;
```

If I log this to the console it logs as:

```
2015-10-08 08:44:51 +0000
```

The above does not cause a delay

When I then go to save it in `Core Data`, I first check if it is null.  However, the following code is what causes the extreme delay:

```
if (lastedited != (id)[NSNull null]){
    [record setValue:lastedited forKey:@"lastedited"];
}
```

### Edit

I have discovered that even taking out the test, the line `[record setValue:lastedited forKey:@"lastedited"]` runs extremely slowly.

This is despite the fact that `lastedited` in the entity is an NSDate in the data model.

And as the line at the top shows it is in the form of an NSDate and logs to the console as `2015-10-08 08:44:51 +0000`

What might be causing the code to run so slowly?

Comment: What is the data type of lastedited field in your core data entity? Is it NSDate  or NSTimeInterval?

Comment: NSDate in the .h file of the core data file as well as viewed in Model.scdatamodeld

Comment: how slow is *slow*?

Comment: up to 30 seconds for 15 items.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you're not simply testing against nil?

```
if (lastedited != nil) {
    ....
}
```

Here's a good overview of the different kinds of nothing in Objective-C/Cocoa: http://nshipster.com/nil/

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with the data type of `lastedited` field in your `Coredata` entity. The data type you are using is `NSDate`, which is of course not a primitive data type supported by `Coredata`. If the data type is not one of the primitive types (like int, float, double, String, NSTimeInterval), Coredata will first convert it into one of the primitive types. In your case, the date is converted to NSTimeInterval just before saving, which is a bulky process and takes more time than expected. So if you are doing the overhead of converting the NSDate to NSTimeInterval before saving, the process will become faster. Try this

```
[record setValue:([lastedited timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000) forKey:@"lastedited"];
```

Don't forget to change the data type of lastedited to NSTimeInterval in .h file of your entity.

```
@property (nullable, nonatomic, copy) NSTimeInterval *lastedited;
```

Keep in mind that you are saving the date as milliseconds to coredata now. So whenever you are fetching it from coredata, convert it to NSDate and use

Comment: from the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdate): *NSDate objects encapsulate a single point in time, independent of any particular calendrical system or time zone. Date objects are immutable, representing an invariant time interval relative to an absolute reference date (00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 2001).* Conceptional  `NSDate` is just an light wrapper around a time interval. So it is very unlikely, that your suggestion will improve the execution time significantly.